Is anyone aware if a Global Action can Invoke a Before Save Flow?
As per the title, I'm wondering if anyone knows if a global action can trigger a before save flow.
My scenario is that I have a global action to create a case record, I also have a before save flow that has several elements that work to stamp fields on the case. When a case is created from the global action, it's as if the before save flow hasn't ran. Just wondering if anyone is aware of this or perhaps I'm incorrect - as I can't find documentation surrounding this online.
Thanks to anyone that takes there time to advise.

A Global Action that creates or update records will initiate the Save sequence as defined in Triggers and Order of Execution - The whole point of the platform is that user admin or dev config to CRUD records would maintain database integrity, regardless of where that CRUD action is initiated from.

Sorry, I realised there was an issue with the before save flow I was expecting to fire leading to the flow firing but going through certain paths and ending. Which I have now fixed.
Just to confirm, Global Actions can invoke before save flows.
